# Реализация очереди в скрипте Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.6

Пишу скрипт для редактирования psd макетов(изменение текстовых слоев) на питоне.
Скрипт открывает Photoshop, редактирует в нем слой и закрывает Photoshop. При работе одного человека со скриптом ошибок нет, но при работе сразу двух клиентов со скриптом вылезает ошибка что Photoshop занят(открыт). Я понимаю что нужно реализовать очередь к скрипту, но не представляю как и при помощи чего это можно реализовать. Скрипт прилагаю ниже

```
def render(text: str, id: str):
import win32com.client
import os
psApp = win32com.client.Dispatch("Photoshop.Application")
psApp.Open("test.psd")
doc = psApp.Application.ActiveDocument
layer_facts = doc.ArtLayers["Your text"]
text_of_layer = layer_facts.TextItem
text_of_layer.contents = text
text_of_layer.size = 150

options = win32com.client.Dispatch('Photoshop.ExportOptionsSaveForWeb')
options.Format = 6   # JPEG
options.Quality = 100 # Value from 0-100

jpgFile = "result.jpg"
doc.Export(ExportIn=jpgFile, ExportAs=2, Options=options)

os.system("TASKKILL /F /IM photoshop.exe")
```

Comment: Да лучше просто проверяйте, что фотошоп уже запущен, например

Comment: а что делать юзеру скрипта? Отправлять сообщение по типу: "Я сейчас занят, перезвоните пожалуйста позже?" :)

Comment: А, в этом смысле. Что кто первый фотошоп открыл, тот пускай всю накопившуюся очередь разгребает? )  Ну кладите все файлы которые нужно обработать в какой-нибудь каталог и пусть запустившийся скрипт это всё разгребает. Можно туда какую-то сопроводиловку в .txt файлах класть, где записывать какие-то параметры обработки. Оно задание - один файл.

Comment: Нет нет. Для каждого юзера рендериться фотка отдельно. Ваш совет использовать txt вполне может стать решением)